# Assigning the same function to different variables

Tags: javascript, wurfl

I was going through the [WURFL.js](http://wurfljs.com/) source, I saw this towards the bottom of the page:

```
var logo=document.getElementById("hero"),heroText=document.getElementById("hero"), ...
```

Obviously, the variables, `logo` and `heroText`, are referring to the same thing. Isn't that an unnecessary overhead on the DOM parsing in JavaScript (since JavaScript has to look for the id `hero` each time)? Apparently, a more efficient one is:

```
var logo=document.getElementById("hero");
var heroText = logo;
```

In that case, `heroText` could be another object or could also be referring to the same object as `logo`. I don't know which because I don't know how the JavaScript interpreter works (I'm a C# person, a learner, though).

So my question is really this: (I'm assuming WURFL didn't make a mistake) how does JavaScript interpret the two lines? Thanks, in advance.

Comment: When it comes to a HTMLElement `logo === heroText` would be true, so yes, it's the same thing and seems uneccessary, but it depends on how it's used I supposed ?

Comment: A lookup by element id is sufficiently fast that it will make no real difference to the behavior of the page.

Answer (score 2):

The difference would be (if it weren't returning a DOM element) that if you do

```
var getObj = function() { return {} };
var a = getObj();
var b = getObj();
a.test = 'hi';
console.log(b);
// Object {}
```

But if you do:

```
var getObj = function() { return {} };
var a = getObj();
var b = a;
a.test = 'hi';
console.log(b);
// Object {test: "hi"}
```

One results in two unique objects, the other in two references to the same object.

```
var a = document.getElementById('notify-container')
var b = document.getElementById('notify-container')
a.test = 'hi'
console.log(b.test);
//"hi"
```

So, in the instance you are showing, yes it is more efficient to do

```
var logo=document.getElementById("hero");
var heroText = logo;
```

Answer (score 1):

There clearly seams to be a mistake. Because `document.getElementById` returns a 'live' representation of a node. That means that whenever that element changes, the variable that holds tha node ( logo, heroText ) is also changed; also, if you check those two variables for equality they will be the same.